# file_get_contents stops at 217 entries

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents

I have the following code for extracting data from a site and putting it into a sql database. It stops at 217 entries, but there are 619 different pages. It fails at this number whether I echo to screen or store it in a database. There's no error message.

Any idea why?

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 619; $i++) {

$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/'.$i.'/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

//get row data and store in variables
$id = $jsonarray['id'];
$name = addslashes($jsonarray['web_name']);
$team = $jsonarray['team_name'];
$pos = $jsonarray['type_name'];
$flag = $jsonarray['status'];
$cost = ($jsonarray['now_cost']/10);
$ownedby = $jsonarray['selected'];
$balance = $jsonarray['transfers_balance'];

$playerupdate = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO playerprices (id, name, team, pos, flag, cost, ownedby, balance) 
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$pos', '$flag', '$cost', '$ownedby', '$balance') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE flag = '$flag', cost = '$cost', ownedby = '$ownedby', balance = '$balance'") 
or die (mysql_error());

}
```

When I echo only the variables for page 216-220, they all work fine so I don't think it's to do with the data on these pages. There's no special characters that I can see.

Comment: Timeout of the script? Try starting the $i at 200 or something, see what happens

Comment: @oli has it right I bet. Check out [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and hope that your host allows you to change it.

Comment: Alternatively, run it from command line (PHP CLI). Timeout limits don't apply to command-line scripts

Comment: @oli & mkaatman: $i works at any number, but fails after 217 entries. I'll try the set_time_limit now.. thanks!

Comment: @mkeaatman - I tried to set_time_limit to 600, 1000 and 2000. They all failed at 322 entries now no matter which I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error (enable [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to view),

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\file_get_contents.php on line 5

try increasing the [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) to 5-10 minutes.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Or alternatively execute your script via [`command line`](http://davidwalsh.name/php-command-line).

> When running PHP from the **command line** the default setting is **0**. (Source: [`PHP.net`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), 2012).

Comment: This kinda works. It now fails at 312 entries, but it's progress at least.. but more importantly tells me that it's just timing out rather than a problem with my code or with the pages it's taking from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If, at any point in your data, there is one or more single quotes your query will fail and trigger the `die()` statement. You can either scrub every variable to remove or replace these characters, or you can move away from the deprecated mysql_* functions and use parameterized queries with mySQLi or PDO. This means:

1. You won't have to scrub special characters out of your input.
2. Your code will be less susceptible to SQL injection.
3. Your code will not generate E_DEPRECATED messages in recent versions of PHP.
4. Your code will not break in future versions of PHP when these functions are removed.
5. Most importantly, peopel will stop endlessly harping on you about the functions you use while ignoring your actual question.

Comment: Ok, but this looks like a file_get_contents or timeout problem rather than a sql problem so I don't see how what you said has anything to do with my question. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather get this working first before trying to move to mySQLi.